# Shutter selection window

Tags: shutter

When I open shutter and click on selection the screen is taken up by the various shortcut keys that can be used with it. That information screen at times blocks what I wish to select. How do I get rid of it or move it out of the way?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the options under

Preferences > Behavior > Window Behavior Selected

I would post a screen shot but I have to receive a few reputation points first ;-)

Comment: post the screenshot to some picturebin (and tell the link :-)), anyone here will be glad to put it into your answer.